# How to get "Open With" programs with their full paths from the registry on Windows with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry

I'm using Qt, and it has a really helpful `QSettings` class that allows to easily access the Windows registry:

```
QSettings s("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.html\\OpenWithList", QSettings::NativeFormat);
```

`s.value("a").toString()` returns `"chrome.exe"`.

Chrome is not in my computer's PATH. Running `chrome.exe` in the terminal results in a not found error. So I can't just run it in my C++ app.

I also can't get the icon for it, as I need full path.

So how do I find this full path? (In case of Chrome it's `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`)

Comment: [AppPaths, most likely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with the registry directly -- [`FindExecutable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419.aspx) is designed to produce exactly what you want/need.

Comment: This function returns only the default program for the extension. I need to get a list of all possible programs, the one you get when clicking "open with" in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Alex: Probably would have been worth mentioning that in the question.

Comment: The title says "open with programs with their full paths" which means that I need to get multiple programs